# Determine the number of samples in audio buffer

Tags: c, audio, portaudio, audio-processing

I am writing a small program to perform real-time ambient noise removal using PortAudio. To do some of the necessary calculations (like Fourier transforms), I need to supply the sample data, but I also need to know exactly how many samples I am working with at a given time.

**How can I determine the number of audio samples in a buffer?**

When attempting to solve this myself, two variables seemed particularly relevant and useful, namely: the sampling rate and the frames per buffer. When I attempted to calculate the number of samples using the sampling rate, I ran into the issue of miscalculating the time between each callback invocation.

```
int ambienceCallback(const void * inputBuffer,
            void * outputBuffer,
            unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
            const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo * timeInfo,
            PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
            void * userData)
{
    const SAMPLE * in = (const SAMPLE *) inputBuffer;
    PaStreamParameters * inputParameters = (PaStreamParameters *) userData;
    PaTime time = timeInfo->inputBufferAdcTime;
    int sampleCount = (time - callbackTime) * Pa_GetDeviceInfo(inputParameters->device)->defaultSampleRate;
    callbackTime = time;
    // extraneous ...
}
```

where `callbackTime` is a variable declared in the header file, and initialized upon starting the audio input stream.

```
// extraneous ...
error = Pa_StartStream(stream);
callbackTime = Pa_GetStreamTime(stream);
// extraneous ...
```

However, the calculated time would always be zero. As a result, I could not make my idea to simply multiply the sampling rate by the elapsed time work. The other variable, `framesPerBuffer` seemed like it could be useful for calculating the sample count if I could find how many samples were in a frame but, I flat out could not manage do that.

Again, how can I **determine how many samples are in the buffer**? As a disclaimer, I am new to audio programming. I am probably mixing up some terms or concepts, causing the more experienced to scratch their heads. (I apologize!)

Comment: One "frame" is one sample, IIRC

Comment: That is, a frame is one sample for each channel; eg. for stereo, one sample for the left channel and one for the right channel.

Comment: @Dmitri Not quite. A frame is a set of samples, not one sample for each channel.

Comment: @dmitri Alright... a set of simultaneously occurring samples, which will often be one per channel when those channels are sampled simultaneously at the same rate?

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of samples from the callback parameters! :)

`framesPerBuffer` gives you number of frames.
A frame is a set of samples that occur simultaneously. For a stereo stream, a frame is two samples.

Timestamps are not useful for your purpose, e.g. `Pa_GetStreamTime()` returns the stream's current time in seconds. This resolution won't allow you to calculate the number of samples.